# Unable to query using WP_Query with new database instance

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm writing REST api in wordpress. The api is in OOP format. I created new instance of $wpdb and the connection works just fine. the only problem I'm unable to query database via `WP_Query()`. But using normal sql, I can get the result.

Whenever I query using WP_Query, it's seems like returning me, the table columns with null value.

**FAILS**

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'custom_type'
);

$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

**SUCCESS**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE post_type ='custom_type'";
 $result = get_results($query);
```

I also tried adding slash before WP_Query like this to no avail:

```
$result = new \WP_Query($args);
```

Where's my mistake here? Someone please advise me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use \ instead of `/`

Comment: @PankajMakwana, that was a typo, sorry

Comment: @PankajMakwana, sorry it was a  typo

Comment: Checkout this documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

You should call have_posts() function in wpquery object

$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

```
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    // The 2nd Loop
    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: it  returns no result

Comment: try call wp_reset_query() before all of that

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest you to use query_posts instead of WP_Query and reset postdata after query.

query_posts lets you to use pagination, excerption and other features.

After query_posts you're free to use a simple [wploop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)